# Video never loads in Firefox but works in chrome

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

I was trying to load this simple video in firefox but when I try to access the video it loads forever and never plays whereas it works perfectly in chrome. It does the exact same thing with every videos I tried. I don't understand why it does not work.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

This is how it looks when I try to open it

[image]

Comment: `html5-video` and `html` seem unrelated, since you're playing the video directly. Any addons/extensions blocking w3schools? There might be something in the DevTools/Network tab. (Works fine here btw)

Comment: 0 addons on my side

Answer (score 0):

It is working in firefox, I think you need to update your browser. Check more for documentation on firefox they have details about it.